# How do I reenable the "Navigate" option in Visual Studio 2017 after installing ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, resharper, dotcover

I have installed JetBrains' dotCover application (not the full ReSharper, but it still manages to get its big, meaty claws on my keybindings and such), and the `Navigate >` option in the context menu is now unavailable.

[image: Navigate option unavailable in VS2017 context menu]

I have configured ReSharper's settings as follows, and have tried other combinations as well:

[image: ReSharper's Keyboard & Menus settings]

I have also tried resetting my keyboard shortcuts by going to **Tools** > **Options** > **Environment** > **Keyboard** and clicking Reset, and Navigate is still unavailable.

All I want is the test runner functionality of dotCover, with *no other changes* to my stock IDE settings. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this, or at the very list, how I can get Navigate back?

Answer (score 1):

This Navigate menu item comes from ReSharper, not from Visual Studio. All Visual Studio navigation-related menu items appear above Navigate item on your screenshot. You might disable dotCover in `Tools | Options | ReSharper Ultimate | Suspend now` and check that Navigate menu item will disappear from the context menu. I've filed [a new request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-468620) to fix this.

Comment: Ah I see. Do you know if Visual Studio has any built in type navigation? What I'm really after is being able to click (or use a hotkey) on a variable and instantly go to its type definition. I'd love to not add the rest of ReSharper's functionality, just this. Any tips?